# Populate Tooltip with Text from Another Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create tooltips on a page to provide definitions to words.  However, these definitions are on another page on the same site.  Is it possible to somehow grab the specific text to display in the tooltip?  I'm able to create a tooltip with jQuery and have it create an iFrame which takes me directly to the definition on the page with an anchor, but I don't feel like this is the most elegant solution, not to mention, it's loading the entire page in the iFrame, which is a little slow.

What do you pose as the best solution?  I wanted to avoid this route, but the more I think about it, a database with words and definitions might be the best.  Then, I could query the DB with Ajax.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a look at this guide on how to ask a good question here: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: Not sure if I totally understand your goal, but if you're doing what I think, I would use PHP: `<?php include 'path/to/file.php';?>`. And in `file.php`, you just enter the tooltip's text, only the text. I use this method for displaying owner/creator credits, so that they can easily be changed without having to open and alter the page's file.

Answer (score 0):

The database option seems to be a bit overkill if you only have a couple hundred key-value pairs. You could add a JSON file to your server and then use AJAX to load the data once the page is loaded. The next step would be to parse the data and load it into the tooltips.

Here's how you can fetch the data:

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
  }).appendTo( "body" );
});
```

I hope this helps!